# Set the default camera to front/back in CodenameOne

Tags: camera, codenameone

Sometimes I want to "scan" documents with the back camera, and sometimes take selfies with the front camera.  Is it possible to set the default camera before calling the Capture.capturePhoto() method?

I see that the default camera is always the one that was last used.

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at the new native camera API which lets you have more control over the camera.

[This blog](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/camerakit-low-level-camera-api.html) is about the library.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like what I need.  However, I can't get the CameraKitDemo to build correctly.  I tried various ways and ended up making a new project (IntelliJ), and copying the source code into the project.  I copied the CameraKitCodenameOne.cnlib into the lib directory, right-clicked on it and chose Codename One/Refresh cn1libs.  It compiles and runs in the IDE (showing only "Loading native camera view", as to be expected.  When I try to build it, I get the following errors on the build server: package com.wonderkiln.camerakit does not exist, cannot find symbol
CameraView, etc.

Comment: Can you ask a separate question describing whatever issues you encountered?

Comment: See new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49857262/build-problems-with-codenameonecamerakit-cn1lib