# Build problems with CodenameOneCameraKit.cn1lib

Tags: build, camera, codenameone

I am trying to run the demo program for the CodenameOne CameraKit: 
https://github.com/codenameone/CameraKitDemo/ after reading
https://www.codenameone.com/blog/camerakit-low-level-camera-api.html
It compiles and runs in the simulator, but when I send it to the server to build, it gives me a build error.

Am I missing something?

I am using the IntelliJ IDE:
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-181.4445.78, built on April 9, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b27 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

macOS 10.13.3
Latest Codename One plugin

Here follows the code, and the errors from the build server.

```
enter code here



package com.test;


import static com.codename1.ui.CN.*;

import com.codename1.camerakit.CameraEvent;
import com.codename1.camerakit.CameraKit;
import com.codename1.camerakit.CameraListener;
import com.codename1.components.FloatingActionButton;
import com.codename1.components.SpanLabel;
import com.codename1.components.ToastBar;
import com.codename1.ui.*;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.LayeredLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager;
import com.codename1.ui.util.Resources;
import com.codename1.io.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout;
import com.codename1.io.NetworkEvent;

/**
 * This file was generated by <a href="https://www.codenameone.com/">Codename One</a> for the purpose 
 * of building native mobile applications using Java.
 */
public class CameraDemo3 {

    private Form current;
    private Resources theme;
    private CameraKit ck;


    public void init(Object context) {
        ck = CameraKit.create();

        // use two network threads instead of one
        updateNetworkThreadCount(2);

        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

        // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
        Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

        // Pro only feature
        Log.bindCrashProtection(true);

        addNetworkErrorListener(err -> {
            // prevent the event from propagating
            err.consume();
            if(err.getError() != null) {
                Log.e(err.getError());
            }
            Log.sendLogAsync();
            Dialog.show("Connection Error", "There was a networking error in the connection to " + err.getConnectionRequest().getUrl(), "OK", null);
        });        
    }

    public void start() {
        if(ck != null && !ck.isStarted()) {
            ck.start();
        }
        if(current != null){
            current.show();
            return;
        }
        Form hi = new Form("Native Camera", new LayeredLayout());
        hi.setScrollableY(false);
        if(ck != null) {
            ck.addCameraListener(new CameraListener() {
                @Override
                public void onError(CameraEvent ev) {
                    // We currently get some errors on Android
                    Log.p(ev.getMessage() + " : " + ev.getExceptionMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onImage(CameraEvent ev) {
                    ToastBar.showInfoMessage("Captured image bytes");
                }

                @Override
                public void onVideo(CameraEvent ev) {
                    ToastBar.showInfoMessage("Captured video: " + ev.getFile());
                }
            });
            hi.add(ck.getView());
            Button video = new Button();
            FontImage.setMaterialIcon(video, FontImage.MATERIAL_VIDEOCAM);
            video.addActionListener(e -> {
                Boolean b = (Boolean)video.getClientProperty("capturing");
                if(b == null) {
                    video.putClientProperty("capturing", Boolean.TRUE);
                    ck.captureVideo();
                    FontImage.setMaterialIcon(video, FontImage.MATERIAL_VIDEOCAM_OFF);
                } else {
                    video.putClientProperty("capturing", null);
                    ck.stopVideo();
                    FontImage.setMaterialIcon(video, FontImage.MATERIAL_VIDEOCAM);
                }
            });
            FloatingActionButton fab = FloatingActionButton.createFAB(FontImage.MATERIAL_CAMERA);
            fab.bindFabToContainer(hi, CENTER, BOTTOM);
            fab.addActionListener(e -> ck.captureImage());

            Button toggleCamera = new Button();
            FontImage.setMaterialIcon(toggleCamera, FontImage.MATERIAL_CAMERA_FRONT);
            Button toggleFlash = new Button();
            FontImage.setMaterialIcon(toggleFlash, FontImage.MATERIAL_FLASH_ON);
            toggleCamera.addActionListener(e -> ck.toggleFacing());
            toggleFlash.addActionListener(e -> ck.toggleFlash());
            Container buttons = BoxLayout.encloseY(video, toggleCamera, toggleFlash);
            buttons.setScrollableY(true);
            hi.add(BorderLayout.east(buttons));
        } else {
            hi.add(BorderLayout.north(new SpanLabel("Loading native camera view")));
        }
        hi.show();
    }

    public void stop() {
        current = getCurrentForm();
        if(current instanceof Dialog) {
            ((Dialog)current).dispose();
            current = getCurrentForm();
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Build Server output:

```
User-level: 1000
Request Args: 
-----------------
java.version=8
ios.NSCameraUsageDescription=We need camera access to grab pictures and videos
ios.newStorageLocation=true
-------------------
Executing: /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/tools/android create project --target android-23 --name CameraDemo3 --path /tmp/build9109673224646903413xxx/CameraDemo3 --activity CameraDemo3Stub --package com.test --gradle --gradle-version 2.0.0 Created directory /tmp/build9109673224646903413xxx/CameraDemo3/src/main/java
Created directory /tmp/build9109673224646903413xxx/CameraDemo3/src/main/java/com/test

...... cut to reduce length .....

Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.
/tmp/build9109673224646903413xxx/CameraDemo3/src/main/java/com/codename1/camerakit/impl/CameraNativeAccessImpl.java:3: error: package com.wonderkiln.camerakit does not exist
import com.wonderkiln.camerakit.*;
^
/tmp/build9109673224646903413xxx/CameraDemo3/src/main/java/com/codename1/camerakit/impl/CameraNativeAccessImpl.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    private CameraView view;
            ^
  symbol:   class CameraView
  location: class CameraNativeAccessImpl
/tmp/build9109673224646903413xxx/CameraDemo3/src/main/java/com/codename1/camerakit/impl/CameraNativeAccessImpl.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    private CameraKitEventListener listener = new CameraKitEventListener() {
            ^
  symbol:   class CameraKitEventListener
  location: class CameraNativeAccessImpl
/tmp/build9109673224646903413xxx/CameraDemo3/src/main/java/com/codename1/camerakit/impl/CameraNativeAccessImpl.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    private CameraKitEventListener listener = new CameraKitEventListener() {
                                                  ^
  symbol:   class CameraKitEventListener
  location: class CameraNativeAccessImpl
/tmp/build9109673224646903413xxx/CameraDemo3/src/main/java/com/codename1/camerakit/impl/CameraNativeAccessImpl.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
                    view = new CameraView(AndroidNativeUtil.getContext());
                               ^
  symbol: class CameraView
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
5 errors
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 7.792 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:40)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.execute(IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.execute(IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.java:24)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:157)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:127)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:244)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:231)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 68 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 18.103 secs
Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
Received result Failure[value=org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=11167, address=[46019278-8ed8-4606-8f74-3c03030b4a25 port:44179, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, /127.0.0.1]], idle=false, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=1240b5d8-39f4-4710-ac85-f3cf1a99af7f,javaHome=/home/ec2-user/jdk1.8.0_45,daemonRegistryDir=/home/ec2-user/.gradle/daemon,pid=11167,idleTimeout=120000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx2048m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).
Process return code is 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you took the cn1lib and tried to use the code instead of installing the cn1lib using the extension manager available in Codename One Settings.

I would suggest installing the extension.

If you would still want to use the code notice you also need to replicate the changes to build hints which are missing. These are within the properties files that are a part of the cn1lib.

Comment: Thank you.  I had just copied and pasted the cn1lib into my libs folder and selected Codename One/Refresh cn1libs.  Using the extension manager under Codename One Preferences, and then selecting Refresh cn1libs, solved the problem.  Now I know how to install cn1libs properly! ;)